# How to get onMouseDown event in go

Tags: go

Is there a simple way to get the mouse events, like when the left button is clicked, and when it is released in `Go` ?

And also is it possible to get that information even is the mouse is not hover the window's program ?

I'd like to draw a square over the screen, between the beginning and the release of the click, to capture that part of the screen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with [robotgo](https://github.com/go-vgo/robotgo) - Golang Desktop Automation

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
)

func main() {

 // mouse events: mleft, mright, wheelDown, wheelUp, wheelLeft, wheelRight.
  mleft := robotgo.AddEvent("mleft")
  if mleft == 0 {
    fmt.Println("you press... ", "mouse left button")
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried robotgo, that is super nice. Except one thing, it doesn't deal with click and release, only release :(